# Is the Language $L=\{(ab)^{3n}\:|\:n\in\mathbb N\}$ regular?

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

Is the language regular?

My application of the pumping lemma suggests: splitting it in $xyz$:
$$
x = \emptyset \mid y= (ab)^{j} \mid z=(ab)^{3n-j}
$$

Pumping up $y$:
$$
xyyz = (ab)^{3n+j} \mid  (ab)^{3n+j}\notin L
$$

Is that correct? Using "The Pumping Game" by Prof. Dr. Edmund Weitz, I couldn't find a solution for this specific language. So I'm not 100% convinced of my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This language is regular:

$L=(ababab)^*$
Where $\{ababab\}$ is trivially regular, and closure of regularity under Kleene star gives us that $L$ is regular.

Alternatively one can construct a regular grammar that generates the language $L$.

Comment: And as to why your proof went wrong: the pumping lemma doesn't let you choose your $x,y,z$, and we could very well have $3|j$ so that $(ab)^{3n+j}$ could be in $L$, not yielding a contradiction

Comment: I understand why I'm wrong. Also if I'd write the (ab)^(3n) like (ababab)^n it's easily visible that I'm able to pump it up as much as I want, the pumping lemma would not be broken.

Comment: But why doesn't the pumping lemma choose my x,y,z? Do you mean in general or how I did it in this specific case?

Comment: The pumping lemma tells you that if your language is regular, for a long enough word, you can pump it up (or down), that is there exists some $x,y,z$ such that you can pump $y$. But you cannot choose them as it seemed to me you did in your original post.

Comment: But am I not choosing a word, satisfying the language & then splitting it in xyz, also satisfying the language. And then pumping it up? At least thats the scheme I've learned.

Comment: Regarding my initial question - wouldn't it already be clear, that it is regular by trying to "choose"/split (Idk if choosing is wrong) a y with the condition |xy| <= p. and |w| >= p and y >= 1; Because (ab)^j would already possibly > p.

Comment: Maybe the confusion comes from the fact that satisfying the pumping lemma doesn't imply being regular. Only the implication regular $\implies$ satisfies pumping lemma is true in general